# android keep my activity on front end

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am opening a pop up from a  pop up activity let say (Activity A) I have to start another activity let say (Activity B). Scenario is I want to open pop up (Activity A) in front of   other activity(Activity B) but in my implementation I am restricted to start  activity(Activity B) from my pop up  activity(Activity A) but pop up(Activity A) should be on top of that (Activity B) Kindly Suggest me if any one have some good solution.
Hope I make some how clear to you.

Comment: Google it
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

and this startActivityForResult

Comment: I did it for Activity A but it open pop up on the backend of activity B